# How can I pull usernames from AD using powershell and the email addresses

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, userid, email-address, get-aduser

I can pull a single username from AD by searching for the email address, but I would like to pull multiple email addresses from the CSV and log them in an output file. I know I need to broaden the search here:  `mail -eq 'john.smith@example.com'` with something such as `-like` or a variable but I'm having difficulty finding a solution.

Code:

```
$InputFile = 'C:\emailaddresses.csv'
$Outputfile = 'C:\usernames.csv'

Import-CSV -Path $InputFile 
      | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq 'john.smith@example.com' } | select SamAccountName } 
      | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current script?

Comment: I am trying to make one that imports a bulk list of email addresses and uses get-ADuser to pull the usernames from AD and export them to a csv file. The current script only pulls the username for the single address I specify.

Comment: Your `emailaddresses.csv` file should contain a header for the column name. Let's say that header is called `Email`. Then your query becomes `Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$($_.Email)'"`.  The `Foreach-Object` processes each pipelined object as `$_` or `$PSItem`. The `$()` is necessary because your filter string performs string expansion on everything inside which would substitute `$_` and then just append `.Email` to it.

Comment: @AdminOfThings this helped, certainly put me in the right direction. I now get the following error for each address on the list.


`Error parsing query: 'mail 'john.smith@example.com'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '6'. At line:1 char:48`

Comment: `+ ... le | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "mail '$($_.Email)'" | selec ...
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`

Comment: Code: `Import-CSV -Path $InputFile | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter "mail '$($_.Email)'" | select SamAccountName } | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: There's no comparison operator in your filter. Try `-Filter "mail -eq '$($_.Email)'"`

Answer (score 0):

the answer is probably spacing and AD calls are a pain note the `$Email`

```
$InputFile = 'C:\emailaddresses.csv'
#assumption that header for the file above is email
$Outputfile = 'C:\usernames.csv'

Import-CSV -Path $InputFile | ForEach-Object { 
    $email = $null
    $email = $_.email
    Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq $email } | Select-Object SamAccountName } | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

I assume the header is email in the first csv and I am not sure if you want `-eq` or `-like` but my answer here will get you there.

I tested this on my machine and it works.